# Laravel File:: and Amazon AWS S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, directory, storage

I am working on a webapp and just started to manage file uploads and stuff.
I know you can use `File::` facade to manage files and directory however now I see Laravel 5 > uses `Storage::` . I also found out that Amazon S3 doesn't rely on the concept of Directories but it uses objects.
So the problem is, if I use the F`ile::` facade to check if a directory exists and then create it if needed and save files into it then how will the webapp behave if I decide to use Amazon AWS? My understanding is it may not work and so how can I use the `Storage::` facade instead to manage the files and directory keeping in mind that it then will work on S3 ?
Example if I need to create directories for users and store pictures uploaded by the user in that created directory how will AWS behave?

Answer (score 1):

You have an adapter for the AWS s3 situated here that you need to install. https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3

Then, you will need to use the `Storage::disk('s3')` to use the package. You will then have access to the functions present on [this file](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/blob/master/src/AwsS3Adapter.php)

For example, if you want to check if a file exists:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->has('myfile.jpg');
```

You also need to enter the identification information in the s3 array on your `config/filesystems.php` on your Laravel installation:

```
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => 'your-key',
    'secret' => 'your-secret',
    'region' => 'your-region',
    'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
],
```

I hope this helps a little bit